# Join more than two tables on a same column

Tags: mysql, sql

For example if I have these three tables in a MySQL database:

Table 1: **wood_items** (columns: wood_item_id, item_name, width, height, thickness, price)

Table 2: **other_items** (columns: other_items_id, item_name, price)

Table 3: **transaction** (columns: transaction_id, item_id, price)

I want to join the **transaction** table with both of **wood_items** and **other_items** table on item_id, so it will display all transaction made (columns to display: transaction_id, item_name, price) regardless whether it's a wood_item or an other_item. It's probably share a similar concept to inheritance in Java, since both of **wood_items** and **other_items** are supposed to be *an item*.

Is it possible to do it? If so, how; but if I can't, what is the best way to create a similar structure/result?

Comment: What fields do you want to get from the query?

Comment: @FilipeSilva I totally forgot to put it on the question. Fixed the question a bit. It's transaction_id, item_name, and price. Thanks!

Comment: check my answer with the UNION it should fit your needs

Comment: @ceyquem Thank's a lot for your answer about union. You give me something new to learn. However, for this case I think I'll go with restructuring my table as Explosion Pills' answer since luckily I haven't gotten very far into the project. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would restructure your tables if you can since there should be only one `items` table, and you can of course have another table for `categories` like "wood."

Failing that, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to remove the requirement that a matching index exist on *both* tables.

```
SELECT cols FROM
transaction
LEFT JOIN wood_items ON (wood_item_id = item_id)
LEFT JOIN other_items ON (other_items_id = item_id)
WHERE
    -- Ensures that there is a match in at least one of the tables
    wood_item_id IS NOT NULL
    OR other_items_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a UNION between wood_items and other_items after the JOIN but for this you need to have a fixed number of columns between wood and other, something like this should work if you select only the 'id' column (I have added a type field to make a difference between which table it comes from):

```
(SELECT T.transaction_id, T.item_id, T.price, W.item_name AS item_name, W.price AS item_price 
FROM transaction T
LEFT JOIN wood_items W ON W.wood_items.wood_item_id = T.transaction.item_id)
UNION (SELECT T.transaction_id, T.item_id, T.price, , O.item_name AS item_name, O.price AS item_price
FROM transaction T
LEFT JOIN other_tiems O On O.other_items.other_items_id = T.transaction.item_id);
```

Edit: I have added the fields you need, it should work as you want.